# What is the term for two figures being congruent and of same orientation?

Tags: terminology

In the plane, two figures are called congruent exactly if one can be transformed into the other by translation, rotation, and reflection. What if reflection is excluded, that is, preservation of orientation is required? Is there a term for the resulting equivalence relation?

Comment: I don't think there's a special name for this. "Orientation-preserving isometry" is probably the most common name for such a map.

Comment: I think the question was about the figures, not the maps.  Although it is clunky, I think it would be immediately clear what you meant if you said that two such figures are "orientation-preserving isometric"; but, anyway, whatever term you use, you should define it!

Comment: To be honest, the notion that reflections would be included in legit "congruence" had slipped my mind, though, now that I think of it, that _is_ consistent with the introductory Euclidean geometry stuff about triangles. As @LSpice says, in this and other situations, it's surely better to say what one means, rather than rely upon volatile terminology...

Comment: Wiktionary suggests [superposable](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/superposable) as opposed to [enantiomorph](//fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/énantiomorphe#Adjectif).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While perhaps not widespread, the term “direct congruence” is used for this equivalence relation.

Comment: I hope you won't mind my repeating my [earlier comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409252/what-is-the-term-for-two-figures-being-congruent-and-of-same-orientation#comment1049872_409252) that, whatever term you use, unless it is absolutely standard in your field, you should define it.

Comment: I've never heard "direct congruence" ... I'd not think that this would be a reliable term for communication...

Comment: I didn’t say I wouldn’t want to define this term. The question was just what term to use. I didn’t want to invent a new term if there was already some term in use.